How can I insert new items for a ChatView using DevExpress's DXCollectionView in .NET Maui?
I am attempting to create a chat view in .NET Maui. For performance reasons I have decided to use DevExpress's DXCollectionView.
When the user first enters the chat, I add a small number of chat items to an ObservableCollection so that the chat populates quickly. I would like to detect if the user scrolled to the top of all available items, and then respond to that by adding additional items at the top.
Since chats typically appear at the bottom of the page, when the user scrolls up the new chat ViewModel instances must be inserted at the beginning of the ObservableCollection. Unfortunately, when this happens, the newly added chats show up, and the chats that were there before "shift down".
I would like to either stop scrolling during the adding of new items, or perhaps keep the list scrolled to the fixed location by setting the scroll position. However, I haven't had much luck with this. If I scroll to position, I have to wait a while (some arbitrary amount) before scrolling. I don't see a way to disable scrolling.
Can anyone provide some tips as to how to solve this problem?
